# Spring boot 2 data JPA: Transaction not rolling back

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa

The transaction is not rolled back, though runtime exception is thrown from the service method.

Repository:

```
public interface SchoolRepository extends CrudRepository<School, Long> {
    School save(School school);
}
```

Service:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class SchoolService {

    @Autowired
    private SchoolRepository schoolRepository;

    @Transactional
    public School save(final School school) {
        schoolRepository.save(school);
        if (true)
            throw new RuntimeException("eee"); // Explicitly throwing exception
        return school;
    }

}
```

The transaction is enabled by using @EnableTransactionManagemen annotation in the class having the main method.

Though the exception is thrown, the saved data is still present in the DB.

**Other Details:**

DB: MySQL, Version = 5.7.18, Engine = MyISAM

Spring boot version: 2.0.2.RELEASE

Please help.

Comment: for starters remove the `save` method as that is already on the `CrudRepository`. Next add which database (and version) you are using (my guess is MySQL together with `MyISAM` tables).

Comment: @M.Deinum: I have removed the save method from the repository. Still same issue. I have updated the question with DB details.

Comment: As I guessed. MyISAM doesn't support transactions, switch to InnoDB.

Comment: Thank you very much @M.Deinum. you are correct. I changed the engine to InnoDB and its working fine! Please add this as an answer and I would mark it as accepted one.